# nginx point API URLs to live website

Tags: nginx

nginx point API URLs to live website

location = http://localhost:5100/services/v1/ {
            proxy_pass   https://test.com/services/v1/;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are listening to port 5100 only in the server block to ensure the redirect only happens on 5100.

```
server {
    listen 5100;
    server_name localhost;

    location /services/v1/ {
        proxy_pass https://test.com/services/v1/;
    }
}
```

Comment: nginx returning 204 no content

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intention is to forward /services/v1/* api requests to test.com, 
    location /services/v1/ 
    { 
    proxy_pass https://test.com/services/v1/; 
    }

Comment: Yes but only for port 5100

Comment: yes true. wanted to emphasis not to use = in location block. thats for exact URI match.